# Can I install Ubuntu Gnome 3.14 over Ubuntu Unity without losing /home?

Tags: unity, gnome, 14.10, ubuntu-gnome

The title says it all. I'm coming from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS then I upgraded to 14.10 still in Unity. I've followed tutorials explaining how to install Gnome 3.14 and I can say that I'm loving it.

The dark side is it has some few bugs being non-native even after every Unity packages have been removed.

Can I just install Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 over it and don't lose any data from my /home ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I just install Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 over it and don't lose any data from my /home ?

No.  Very simple: even a small error could render your system unusable with just a grub recovery prompt or not even that. Nobody can predict a power failure. Or you pressing the reset button or pulling a cord from the machine.

You never mess with desktop enviroments, filesystems, videocard configurations without making an extra backup and making sure you can restore that backup.

And extra: also always make sure you have a working Live DVD so you can restore that backup from the Live DVD.

If you do that: feel free to mess around with anything even /home. All your files are safe (well at least for the time you need to install a new desktop).

Answer (score 2):

1.Make a separate home partition,you’ll have to create a new partition (which may require resizing your existing partitions).

2.Copy the files from your existing home directory to that partition(/home)

And its safer to install any new distro you want.

Comment: Your answer is good too, I picked up the other one because my question was explicitly without making any changes in my partition. Thanks for the explanation ! I think I may do that + backing up things !

Comment: Its OK friend ! Arnaud Janssens